# arrayfun on nested list in R

Tags: r

I need to multiply each columns of a submatrix in a list of matrices with a column as follows and then sum over columns. I can do this via for loop but the list could consists of more than 1000 submatrices and this may not be very efficient. Will appreciate any help with vectorized version of this.

```
install.packages(c("pracma"))
 library(pracma)
### generate nested list
l1<-matrix(c(1:8),nrow=2)
l2<-matrix(c(4:11),nrow=2)
l3<-matrix(c(1:16),nrow=4)
l4<-matrix(c(6:21),nrow=4)
l<-list(l1,l2)
ll<-list(l3,l4)
lll<-list(l,ll)



lll
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    3    5    7
[2,]    2    4    6    8

[[1]][[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    4    6    8   10
[2,]    5    7    9   11


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    5    9   13
[2,]    2    6   10   14
[3,]    3    7   11   15
[4,]    4    8   12   16

[[2]][[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    6   10   14   18
[2,]    7   11   15   19
[3,]    8   12   16   20
[4,]    9   13   17   21

# multiply  each column of matrices in lll by m
m1<-list(as.matrix(c(1:2)),as.matrix(c(3:4)))
m2<-list(as.matrix(c(5:8)),as.matrix(c(9:12)))
m<-list(m1,m2)
  m
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    2

[[1]][[2]]
     [,1]
[1,]    3
[2,]    4


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
     [,1]
[1,]    5
[2,]    6
[3,]    7
[4,]    8

[[2]][[2]]
     [,1]
[1,]    9
[2,]   10
[3,]   11
[4,]   12

 sum_k<-list()
 sum_l_<-list()
  for (l in 1:2){

    for(k in 1:2){
      sum=colSums(arrayfun('*',lll[[l]][[k]],m[[l]][[k]]))
      sum_k[[k]]<-sum
  }
  sum_l_[[l]]<-sum_k
}

[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1]  5 11 17 23

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 32 46 60 74


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1]  70 174 278 382

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 320 488 656 824
```

Comment: I honestly think this is a great use of pracma::arrayfun. I also tend to think loops for assignment and keeping the structure of your nested lists are the way to go. Short of initializing your list creation step, I'm not sure a better method. I have edited your code so it is clean and unintimidating for others! cheers